# Haskell: "Cast" / force type?

Tags: haskell, types, casting

How do I say Haskell to interpret something as a special type?
For example, I have a list and want to divide its length by 2.
So I write

```
(length mylist) / 2
```

and get this error

> No instance for (Fractional Int)
>         arising from a use of `/'

As I want a whole-number division, I'd like to make `length mylist`, `2` and the result `Int`.

Comment: JFI there is `genericLength` function in `Data.List`. In your case it will not return whole-number answer, but it's generally useful as it lets you avoid some awkward `fromIntegral` calls.

Comment: Needs more `fromIntegral`. Seriously, though, `fromIntegral` is the magical way to "cast" an Int to anything that instantiates the `Num` typeclass.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two different issues here.

- Integer division: Use the `div` function : `div (length mylist) 2` or `` (length mylist) `div` 2 ``
- Casting. One can tell Haskell that a particular expression has a particular type by writing `expression :: type` instead of just `expression`. However, this doesn't do any "casting" or "conversion" of values. Some useful functions for converting between various numeric and string types are `fromIntegral`, `show`, `read`, `realToFrac`, `fromRational`, `toRational`, `toInteger`, and others. You can look these up on [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/).

Answer (score 5):

Try `div (length my list) 2`. `/` does fractional division; `div` does integer division.

Comment: Ah, thanks.
And how to do it in general?
Do you always have to stick to functions type definition?

Comment: There are functions that allow you to convert from one type to another (such as an integer to a fractional), but yes, the nature of Haskell is such that if the types don't fit into the definition of a function, you *will* get an error.